# NEST version 1.3.1 supported Elasticsearch version(s)

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I'm looking to upgrade my Elasticsearch cluster to 1.4.5 or 1.5 and was curious if this upgrade will break my current codebase.

We are using NEST 1.3.1 in our code and I want to see if this version supports Elasticsearch 1.4.5 and higher? If you could link some documentation regarding this support, that would help me tremendously. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

Did you consider upgrading Nest? Within the same major version, it is pretty much always backward compatible. With an older version of Nest and newer version of Elasticsearch, you would miss out on being able to use any new features that the newer version of Elasticsearch may provide. Anyways, you can read about the release notes of Nest [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/releases).